# How to change the text of a label depending on click

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

Im trying to change the text label depending on click. Here is the code

```
  If btn_com_Click() = True Then
            Me.price.Text = "PRICE"
        ElseIf btn_stock_Click() Then
            Me.price.Text = "QUANTITY"

     End If
```

Comment: Welcome, take the [tour]. Would you consider putting your code in the button click event?

Answer (score 0):

You could write two handlers like this:

```
Private Sub btn_com_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn_com.Click
    price.Text = "PRICE"
End Sub

Private Sub btn_stock_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn_stock.Click
    price.Text = "QUANTITY"
End Sub
```

But it's a bit uncommon to use push buttons to solve that, you might rather use a radio group with two radio buttons or a dropdown instead.